# Proving the validity of a kernel

Tags: kernel-trick, integral

How can we prove that the following is a valid kernel?

Let $\phi$ be any function on R X R.

Define: $K(x,y) = \int{\phi(x,z)\phi(y,z)dz}$

We want to show that $K$ is a valid kernel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you are referring to a positive definite kernel. A kernel $K: \mathcal{X} \times \mathcal{X} \to \mathbb{R}$ is positive definite (valid) if for all $n=1,2,\ldots$, and for all $x_1,\ldots, x_n \in \mathcal{X}$, we have

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n \alpha_i \alpha_j K(x_i, x_j) \ge 0. $$

You kernel is valid because

$$\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n \alpha_i \alpha_j K(x_i, x_j) &= &
\int \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i \phi(x_i, z) \sum_{j=1}^n \alpha_j \phi(x_j, z) dz \\
&=& \int \left(\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i \phi(x_i, z)\right)^2 dz \ge 0.
\end{eqnarray}$$